# What is the equivalent of T-SQL ISNUMERIC function in HANA Sqlscript?

Tags: sql, sql-scripts, hana

I have a requirement where I need to convert all SQL Server stored procedures into HANA stored procedures. I have come across a function ISNUMERIC in T-SQL and I am not getting the equivalent of it in HANA.

After searching the web, I found that HANA does not have built in ISNUMERIC equivalent function. Then I tried writing my own function to achieve this and there I stuck with error handling and regular expression limitations.

My HANA version is 70.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAP HANA does not come with a `ISNUMERIC()` function.
However, this question had been asked and answered multiple times on SCN:
E.g. http://scn.sap.com/thread/3449615

or my approach from back in the days:
http://scn.sap.com/thread/3638673

```
drop function isnumeric;
create function isNumeric( IN checkString NVARCHAR(64))
returns isNumeric integer
language SQLSCRIPT as
begin
declare tmp_string nvarchar(64) := :checkString;
declare empty_string nvarchar(1) :='';

/* replace all numbers with the empty string */
tmp_string := replace (:tmp_string, '1', :empty_string);
tmp_string := replace (:tmp_string, '2', :empty_string);
tmp_string := replace (:tmp_string, '3', :empty_string);
tmp_string := replace (:tmp_string, '4', :empty_string);
tmp_string := replace (:tmp_string, '5', :empty_string);
tmp_string := replace (:tmp_string, '6', :empty_string);
tmp_string := replace (:tmp_string, '7', :empty_string);
tmp_string := replace (:tmp_string, '8', :empty_string);
tmp_string := replace (:tmp_string, '9', :empty_string);
tmp_string := replace (:tmp_string, '0', :empty_string);

/*if the remaining string is not empty, it must contain non-number characters */
if length(:tmp_string)>0 then
    isNumeric := 0;
else  
    isNumeric := 1;
end if;

end;
```

Testing this shows:
    with data as(  select '1blablupp' as VAL from dummy
                   union all select '1234' as VAL from dummy
                   union all select 'bla123' as val from dummy)

```
select val, isNumeric(val)  from data 

VAL         ISNUMERIC(VAL)
1blablupp   0            
1234        1            
bla123      0
```

Comment: This is not complete: what about -100, 1.000.000, etc.

Answer (score 3):

From SAP HANA 1.0 SPS12 you can use regular expressions in SQL. You can use `LIKE_REGEXPR` function to check if specific string contains letters i.e.:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN '0001A' LIKE_REGEXPR '[A-Z]' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
FROM 
  DUMMY;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should cover really **all strings that are convertable as a number**:

```
PROCEDURE "SCHEMA"."package::IS_NUMERIC" ( 
        in stringToCheck nvarchar(5000)
        ,out isNumeric integer 
) 
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
    --DEFAULT SCHEMA <default_schema_name>
    READS SQL DATA AS
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    isNumeric := 0;
END;

select cast(:stringToCheck as double) from dummy; 

isNumeric := 1;

END;
```

e.g. **also covers**: `call "SCHEMA"."package::IS_NUMERIC"('-12.345', ?)`

Comment: You're right, this very old solution didn't cover a huge range of cases. Partly this was due to the HANA limitations back in SP6/7. Your approach to actually performing the conversion and reporting success or failure is obviously correct.

Comment: However, often the requirements can be more specific (i.e. also ignoring commas, full stops and currency symbols like the T-SQL version does it). Also, the use of the procedure (why procedure for a single scalar value?) introduces quite some overhead. Alternatively one could use regex to have a close-enough check: `MAP (locate_regexpr(START '[^0-9\-\.\,\+e]' FLAG 'i' in id_char), 0, 1, 0)`. Using this on 10 Mio rows took 8.5 secs while the procedure/function took 19.5 secs on my test system. What's best here really depends on the use case.